# (Dart) How can I create a sub list of only certain items in the first list containing a string?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

Here is my are my List Items:

```
static List<Category> getMockedCategories(){
  return[
    Category(
      name: "Ascent",
      imgName: "AscentLoading",
      subCategories: [
        SubCategory(
          name: "ascent",
            imgName: "ascent_a_sova_frontgen"
        )
      ]
    ),
    Category(
        name: "Breeze",
        imgName: "BreezeLoading",
        subCategories: [
        ]
    ),
```

The category class:

```
class Category{
  String name;
  String imgName;
  List<Category>? subCategories;

  Category(
    {
      required this.name,
      required this.imgName,
      this.subCategories
    }
    );
}
```

The Subcategory Class:

```
class SubCategory extends Category {

    SubCategory({
      required String name,
      required String imgName,
    }): super(
      name: name,
      imgName: imgName
    );
}
```

When trying to create a ListView of my images with only a certain name in their imgName I am running into this error:
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following RangeError was thrown building SelectedCategoryPage(dirty):
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

If  comment out the catList section and just have pointer pointing at the selectedCategory.subCategories it works fine. I can't see why its not working for catList. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the code for the page running into the issue:

```
var catList = [];
for(int j = 0; j <= selectedCategory.subCategories!.length; j++){
  if( selectedCategory.subCategories![j].imgName.contains(globals.agentSelected) ){
    catList.add(selectedCategory.subCategories![j]);
  }
}
var pointer = selectedCategory.subCategories;
if(catList[0] != null){
  pointer = catList.cast<Category>();
}
```

Tried creating another List of Categories to pass to listview builder but am receving an error on it:
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following RangeError was thrown building SelectedCategoryPage(dirty):
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try changing:
`j <= selectedCategory.subCategories!.length` to `j < selectedCategory.subCategories!.length`

`j` cannot have a position equals to the length of subCategories.

You can also do this:

```
var pointer = selectedCategory.subCategories;
if(catList.isNotEmpty){
  pointer = catList.cast<Category>(); //Try using a for loop here if this statement gives you an error
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, The second part fixed the error but it is still showing all the images from the original list.

Comment: would just like to say that it was because I wasn't ignoring the case in my comparison so the error was really just from <= to < so thanks for the help!